# What do triple curly braces indicate?

Tags: templates, laravel

I've been doing research on this topic. My friend keeps doing things like:

```
{{{blog_posts}}}
```

What do template placeholders do?

Comment: It's probably just markup for a templating engine. Tell your mate to stop being a dick.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: "You have a lot to learn" omg let him come enlighten us all !

Comment: What a nice friend you have.

Comment: Yeah, not good with helping… He usually just changes the whole thing instead of helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are template placeholders. [The Blade engine (used in Laravel), for example, uses `{{{...}}}` as template placeholders](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#other-blade-control-structures).

Answer (score 0):

This got nothing with PHP. It's basically `placeholder` used by templating engine like `Blade` (and triple `{{{` may mean escaped content vs. double `{{` one).

Comment: This is something completely different and refers to HEREDOC: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Yes I know heredoc… I meant he defines his templates with {{{}}}

Comment: IT's most likely Blade templating engine syntax: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates